# WAPP php can not run task scheduler

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have created an application which creates a few tasks in windows task scheduler for some purpose

I have tested it on xampp server and it works perfectly fine, but now I have been asked to shift from xampp to wapp to support postgreSQL

My problem is that the same application does not work on WAPP.

The error being displayed is:

```
Source: Unknown
Description: Unknown
```

I am aware of using COM class to start a task scheduler, and have already added the dotnet COM library to php.ini, there may be something missing in the php.ini that prevents it from starting the task scheduler

how do I correctly configure/ install COM library in WAPP

Link to WAPP: https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp

Comment: The error output is generated by the COM wrapper? So the basic question is how to install and configure the COM library?

Comment: i have edited it, yes may be i havnt correctly installed it, but i did the same procedure as i did with xampp

Comment: Same server? Why didn't you stick with your xampp installation and just exchange mysql with postgres?

Comment: because they want everything in one package on their system, rather than installing postgres separately

Comment: Is there any other COM target you can test the COM library against?

Comment: Yes, i have check the CPU temperature function that I created, and its working fine with COM class, but why doesnt task scheduler work

Comment: So, you have the same code and the same server. One COM operation works and one not? Is the version of the COM library the same?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any solution, I would just stick to Xampp server till I find a solution

Thank you Markus